# Magento2: How to add a custom extra field for product options, such as an image upload, in the select option type

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, custom-options

I want to add custom field for image upload in custom option value like given in image. I tried following Magento 2 add new custom option image upload field but it add earlier while i need it with custom option value.

[image]

Comment: **Here is the solution for the same:** To add an extra field to Magento product custom options, you can refer to the following link: https://www.mageworx.com/blog/how-to-add-a-field-to-custom-options-in-magento-2 Using the above link, you can easily add an additional field to the custom options. The link provided demonstrates how to create a text field, but you can modify it to add an image field instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below Solution based on your requirement**

app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool"
                 type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom-options-images" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">
                        Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">55</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions as OriginalCustomOptions;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductOptions\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options\Price as ProductOptionsPrice;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class CustomOptions extends OriginalCustomOptions
{
    const FIELD_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME = 'image';

    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ConfigInterface $productOptionsConfig
     * @param ProductOptionsPrice $productOptionsPrice
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface      $locator,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ConfigInterface       $productOptionsConfig,
        ProductOptionsPrice   $productOptionsPrice,
        UrlInterface          $urlBuilder,
        ArrayManager          $arrayManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface  $scopeConfig
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct(
            $locator,
            $storeManager,
            $productOptionsConfig,
            $productOptionsPrice,
            $urlBuilder,
            $arrayManager
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->createCustomOptionsPanel();
        $this->setColumnOrder('image', 35);
        return $this->meta;
    }

    protected function createCustomOptionsPanel()
    {
        $this->meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::GROUP_CUSTOM_OPTIONS_NAME => [
                    'children' => [
                        static::GRID_OPTIONS_NAME => $this->getOptionsGridConfig(10),
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

    protected function getOptionsGridConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'children' => [
                        static::CONTAINER_OPTION => [
                            'children' => [
                                static::GRID_TYPE_SELECT_NAME => $this->getSelectTypeGridConfig(10),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        $imagesGrid = [
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'children' => [
                        static::FIELD_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME => $this->getImgConfig(10),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $imagesGrid;
    }

    private function getImgConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Swatch Image'),
                        'componentType' => 'field',
                        'formElement' => 'fileUploader',
                        'dataScope' => 'image',
                        'dataType' => 'file',
                        'fileInputName' => 'image',
                        'sortOrder' => 35,
                        'isMultipleFiles' => false,
                        'elementTmpl'        => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader',
                        'previewTmpl'     => 'Magento_Catalog/image-preview',
                        'uploaderConfig' => [
                            'url' => 'helloworld/index/upload',
                            'imageUrl' => 'tttt',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param int $order
     * @return void
     */
    private function setColumnOrder(string $name, int $order)
    {
        $columns = &$this->meta[static::GROUP_CUSTOM_OPTIONS_NAME]['children'][static::GRID_OPTIONS_NAME]
        ['children']['record']['children'][static::CONTAINER_OPTION]['children'][static::GRID_TYPE_SELECT_NAME]
        ['children']['record']['children'];
        $columns[$name]['arguments']['data']['config']['sortOrder'] = $order;
    }
}
```